# Find linux kernel version of a router firmware from the filesystem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, router, firmware

I've downloaded the file `DAP2690-firmware-v101-rc019.bin` ([link](http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Wireless/DAP-2690/Firmware/1.01/)) which is a firmware update to some D-Link router.

I've extracted it using `binwalk -e DAP2690-firmware-v101-rc019.bin` (Binwalk v1.2b) and now I have the root filesystem in the folder `squashfs-root`.

I'd like to know the linux kernel version of this firmware only from the extracted files (preferably only from the folder `squashfs-root`).

How can I do this?

Comment: This may be useful: http://plastilinux.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-know-version-of-kernel-without.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The file `vmlinuz` doesn't exists in `squashfs-root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along side the `squashfs-root` folder there was a `A0` file.

`binwalk A0` revealed:

```
 DECIMAL    HEX         DESCRIPTION
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0           0x0         ELF 64-bit MSB MIPS32 rel2 executable, MIPS, version 1 (SYSV)
    2969600     0x2D5000    Linux kernel version "2.6.16.26-Cavium-Octeon (william@J10) (gcc version 4.1.1 (Cavium@J10) (gcc version 4.1.1 (Cavium Networks Development Build)) "
    2991185     0x2DA451    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x40, dictionary size: 2097152 bytes, uncompressed size: 2097216 bytes
    3329399     0x32CD77    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x40, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
    3429479     0x345467    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x40, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 131072 bytes
    3429503     0x34547F    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x40, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 131072 bytes
    3429527     0x345497    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x40, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 131072 bytes
    3504750     0x357A6E    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5B, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 88 bytes
    3915776     0x3BC000    gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Thu Mar 11 16:11:03 2010, max compression
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go and check the modules that were compiled on the filesystem.
Every module has a `vermagic` number, which must be equal to the kernel vermagic in order for `insmod` to load the module.

Here is a [link](http://plastilinux.blogspot.co.il/2009/11/how-to-know-version-of-kernel-without.html) describing exactly how to extract it.
It also shows how to use `strings` in order to look for the kernel version.